# How to load React components from external library which contain Tailwind classes for Next.js app?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am abstracting some of my reusable UI into a standalone NPM package/library, and there are several React components in it which contain Tailwind CSS classes. My tailwind.config.js is defined in my main Next.js app currently, not sure if I should move some of that over to the library as well. But main question is, how do I get the build process to add the CSS selector definitions to the output CSS build file, from the components using the CSS in the standalone separate library?

For example, in my standalone library I used the `justify-between` Tailwind class, but didn't use this in my Next.js app. What's happening is the `.justify-between` selector/class CSS code is not added to the output CSS build, and the style isn't being applied when using that external component in my Next.js app.

I have basically this in my next.config.js if that makes any difference:

```
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: [
    '@my/ui-kit',
  ],
}
```

Otherwise, Tailwind *normally* "just works" with Next.js's `pnpm dev` command. Why isn't it working now? How can I get the Tailwind CSS classes to be added to the final build? Do I need to do something with postcss.config.js or anything?

### Update

Adding this to my `tailwind.config.js` seems to get it to work, is this the "correct" way?

```
const config = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './node_modules/@my/ui-kit/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
```

I also saw [this gist](https://gist.github.com/somebody32/48277662e55dd450d542724bc989c62d), not sure if I should go down that road either.